# Pass data from View to Controller using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to pass customer data from View to Controller. I'm referencing [this](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Pass-Send-List-of-objects-from-View-to-Controller-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx) article, and [this](https://fildev.net/2017/05/14/send-array-from-view-to-controller-as-class-asp-net-core/?unapproved=20644&moderation-hash=c00ccf24cb6086f1bc910e5af4da7d0b#comment-20644) article to work on the below code.

Written below code in the `UploadFileUsingJQueryAJAX.cshtml` file.

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Upload File Using jQuery AJAX";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
<form id="myForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="UploadFileUsingJQueryAJAX" asp-controller="Home">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtFirstName" name="txtFirstName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtLastName" name="txtLastName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Photo:</td>
            <td><input type="file" id="photo" name="postedFile" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Photo:</td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="AjaxFormSubmit();" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/js/upload_file_using_jquery_ajax_script.js"></script>
}
```

Below is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var customerId = $('#txtCustomerId').val();
        var name = $('#txtName').val();
        var country = $('#txtCountry').val();

        //Get the reference of the Table's TBODY element
        var tBody = $('#tblCustomers > tbody')[0];

        //Add Row.
        var row = tBody.insertRow(-1);

        //Add CustomerId cell
        var cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        cell.html(customerId);

        //Add Name cell
        var cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        cell.html(name);

        //Add Country cell
        cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        cell.html(country);

        //Add Remove Button cell
        cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        var btnRemove = $("<input />");
        btnRemove.attr("type", "button");
        btnRemove.attr("onclick", "Remove(this);");
        btnRemove.val("Remove");
        cell.append(btnRemove);

        //Clear the TextBoxes
        $('#txtCustomerId').val('');
        $('#txtName').val('');
        $('#txtCountry').val('');
    });
});

function Remove(button) {
    // Determine the reference of the row the button being clicked
    var row = $(button).closest('tr');
    var customerId = $('td', row).eq(0).text();
    var confirmResult = confirm('Are you sure to delete customer details with id: ' + customerId);
    if (confirmResult) {
        //Get the reference of the table
        var tblCustomers = $('#tblCustomers')[0];
        var rowIndex = row[0].rowIndex;
    }
}

$('#btnSave').click(function () {
    //Loop through the table rows and build a JSON array
    var customers = [];
    $('#tblCustomers tbody tr').each(function () {
        var row = this;
        customerId = row.cells[0].textContent;
        name = row.cells[1].textContent;
        country = row.cells[2].textContent;
        customers.push({CustomerId: customerId, Name: name, Country: country});
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: '/Home/InsertCustomers',
        data: JSON.stringify(customers),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {

        },
        error: function (err) {

        }
    });
});
```

Below is the `Customer` class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the code in the Controller.

```
    public IActionResult PassMultipleCustomersFromViewToController()
    {
        var customers = new List<Customer>();
        return View(customers);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult InsertCustomers([FromBody]Customer[] customers)
    {
        return Json(customers);
    }
```

I've inserted two records like shown below:

[image: Inserted two records]

But, I'm unable to pass data from View to Controller.

[image: customers parameter is null]

I must have done some small mistake, but I'm unable to figure it out. Can someone help me to identify the issue!

I've showed above how I've tried to resolve the issue

Comment: Check your browser network tab, on the POST line, check *payload*.  Is your data correct and being sent in the body?

Comment: Do you provide the wrong code about your page? The page is not what you showed in image.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, as @freedomn-m suggested in comment, you can capture the request and check the actual posted data in browser Network tab, and make sure the type and value are correct in request payload.

And from [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#type-conversion-errors), you could find:

*If a source is found but can't be converted into the target type, model state is flagged as invalid. The target parameter or property is set to null or a default value*

Besides, you can also debug and check if the model state is valid, and find the detailed errors, like below.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult InsertCustomers([FromBody] Customer[] customers)
{
    var isvalid = ModelState.IsValid;
    if (!isvalid)
    {
        var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
    }


    //...
```

[image]